# Need to remove duplicate text from file names dynamically

Tags: c#, .net

Due to a bug in their exporter, a client has a list of files where the file name is being duplicated.

For example:

- ThisIs-MyFile-1ThisIs-MyFile-1.jpg
- ThisIs-MyFile-2ThisIs-MyFile-2.jpg

While fixing the exporter is obviously the best solution, in the meantime, it would be great to be able to correct the files that they've already exported. I would like to iterate over these files and find the duplicate text in each string and remove it.

How might this be implemented?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
To be clear, the file names do not share the pattern above in that it isn't just a matter of the number changing. Those are simply placeholders for repeated names.

It could just as easily be:

- heyHowAreYou-1heyHowAreYou-1.png
- ImOkThanksImOkThanks.pdf

Comment: use half of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderpath);
var files = dir.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo f in files)
{
    var oldname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name);
    var newname = oldname.Substring(0, oldname.Length / 2);
    File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.Replace(oldname, newname));
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly the kind of thing I need. Thanks so much. A lot of great answers. I'm almost embarrassed I asked (I was waaay over thinking it worrying about matching pattern instead of just length/2). This answer went above and beyond by implementing the file iteration. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the filename is always duplicated, you can do something like this:

- Grab the filename and the extension of the file you want to "fix"
- Remove half of the filename (the duplicated part)
- Rename the file using the fixed name

So you should end up with something like this

```cs
string originalFile = "ThisIs-MyFile-1ThisIs-MyFile-1.jpg";
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(originalFile);
fileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length / 2);
File.Move(originalFile, $"{fileName}{extension}");
```

Of course you should find a way to iterate in a folder instead of manually specify the file names, but that is up to you

Answer (score 0):

As commented take the half of the string.

Try this:

```
fileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length / 2);
```

I assume fileName is the name of the file without file extension

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var file = "ThisIs-MyFile-1ThisIs-MyFile-1.jpg";

// Split to remove file extension.
var splits = file.Split(new[] { '.' });

// Take half the file name.
var fileName = splits[0].Substring(0, splits[0].Length/2);

// Add the extension back.
var newFile = $"{fileName}.{splits[1]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `FileInfo.Extension` property to remove the extension, then substring half the string and concatenate with the extension:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
var nameWithoutExtension = fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, string.Empty);
var newName = $"{nameWithoutExtension.Substring(0, nameWithoutExtension.Length / 2)}{fileInfo.Extension}";
```